# Upload from CSV to myphp admin using php

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have a csv file that is uploaded every night for next day's work.

This is the insert command:

```
 $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
     $data = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $data);
        if($i>0) {
    $import="INSERT into patientinfo(PATNUM,PATNAME,AGE,SEX,SCHDT,SCHTM,SURGEON,TASK,PTIS1COMP,PTIS2COMP,PTIS3COMP,SERVTYPE,DURATION,ORRoom,DIAG01,COMMENT1,COMMENT2,COLBY_Arrival_time_1,UR_PreAdmission_Plan_1,UR_IMFM_req_1,UR_IMFM_req_2,Smoke_Signal_MRSA_Positive_1,Smoke_Signal_VRE_Positive_1) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]','$data[12]','$data[13]','$data[14]','$data[15]','$data[16]','$data[17]','$data[18]','$data[19]','$data[20]','$data[21]','$data[22]')";
            mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
            }
            $i++;
        }
```

The problem I am having is the `UR_IMFM_req_2` field is always uploading to the last column no matter what I do.  If I delete the `UR_IMFM_req_2`, field and the last `$data[22]` field and delete the column from the csv, it uploads just fine.

Here is some sample data - only Judy Johnson uploads correctly:

```
PATNUM    123456      123457          123458
PATNAME    Jane Doe   Sandy Smith       Judy Johnson
AGE         35          47               60
SEX          F           F               F
SCHDT       30816       30816            30816
SCHTM      0700          0915            1200
SURGEON     Surgeon1     Surgeon2         Surgeon1
TASK       Hip           Shoulder         Knee
PTIS1COMP   Ins1          Ins1              Ins1
PTIS2COMP   Ins2          None             None
PTIS3COMP   Ins3          None             None
SERVTYPE     INPT         OBS              INPT
DURATION     1:30         0:45              2:00
LOCADESC     OR1          OR2               OR1
DIAG01       Hip          Shoulder          Knee         
COMMENT1     test          test             test 
COMMENT2      test          test            test
COLBY_Arrival_time_1  06:30   07:00         10:00
UR_PreAdmission_Plan_1  none    Talk to      None
UR_IMFM_req_1  IMFM Req                  
UR_IMFM_req_2  IMFM Req       IMFM Req     
Smoke_Signal_MRSA_Positive_1                     Yes
Smoke_Signal_VRE_Positive_1
```

Comment: do a `var_dump($data)` and see what's coming out of the csv in the first place. if php isn't reading it correctly, then it's certainly not going to go into mysql correctly either. Plus, where are you initializing $i? What's the points of the `$i > 0` test? If you don't initialize to to non-zero beforehand, you'll be skipping at least ONE of the data rows returned from the csv.

Comment: Is your iterator `$i` defined earlier or not at all? Are we seeing a section of a for loop or something?

Comment: Here is the start of the code
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $i=0;
 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
  echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
  echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
  readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
 }

Comment: Here is the data it shows uploaded
1522987,Guest1,79,F,30816,7:30,SURG1,TOTAL KNEE,NORIDIAN ,BLUE CROSS,NOT FOUND,INPT,2:30,OR 03,.RCX3,TOTAL KNEE,,530,Will see ,IMFM required,IMFM required, 1533597,Doe Jane,63,F,30816,9:00,Surg1,EXCISION,DAKOTACARE,NOT FOUND,NOT FOUND,OP,0:30,OR09,.LATEX,RT EXCISION,,730,,,TRICare Required, 1537577,SMIT SUE,57,F,30816,12:00,SURG2,I AND D EXTREMITY,NORIDIAN ,DEPARTMENT,NOT FOUND,OBS,1:00,OR03,.RCX1,LEFT KNEE,,1030,,,,MRSA Positive

Comment: "MRSA Positive" that can't be good :P Anyway, try enabling debug messages temporarily. Add these two lines right after "<?php" and see if it tells you anything useful. `error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Comment: No errors listed.
remember - if I delete the second IMFM column in the CSV file and remove that from the insert command - everything works perfectly.

Comment: @KathyKaiserLees Yes, that's weird. On another note, your PHP script is using an old mySQL API. It would probably be best to rewrite it and use PDO instead. It would allow you to use prepared statements rather than error prone, injectable string concatenations and it has built-in CSV-insert features (LOAD INTO). Which PHP version are you running?

Comment: We are on 5.5.9 for PHP  Do you have any tutorials on the PDO stuff?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105603/discussion-between-jdo-and-kathy-kaiser-lees).